# C# master class that calls other classes with similar properties

Tags: c#, class

I have a lot of classes that store different types of data but manipulate the data differently. Is there someway I can abstract what class I'm using...and just call the class's methods? I will have one object that I'm using at a given moment, masterclass.

For example I have class1 and class2. Both classes can do .add .subtract...etc.

I want to say...masterclass is now class1. So I can do masterclass.add instead of class1.add. Then change masterclass to class2 and do a masterclass.subtract instead of class1.subtract.

### Ok...maybe this is clearer:

```
class cat
{
    String legs="4 legs";
    String claws="cat has lots of claws";
    public string GetLegs()
    { return legs+claws;
    }
}
class bird
{
    String legs="2 wings";
    String talons="Bird has 2 talons";
    public string GetLegs()
    { return legs+talons;
    }
}
class animal;

mainfunction()
{
    string temp;

    animal = cat;
    temp = animal.GetLegs();
    animal = bird;
    temp = animal.getLegs();    
}
```

Comment: Search info about inheritance, abstract classes, interfaces and generic classes, it will give you an idea about what you can do.

Comment: Isn't that called inheritance?

Comment: Look into interfaces. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173156.aspx

Comment: You're probably talking about a virtual method defined in a base class (call it `MyBase`), and overridden in `class1` and `class2`, both of which are derived from the base class. You can have a refernece to `MyBase`, assign an instance of either `class1` or `class2` to it, call the virtual method, and it'll call the one belonging to the actual instance.

Comment: What is your question specifically? What are you hoping your idea answer would contain?

Comment: I looked into inheritance and abstract classes. Inheritance won't work because it allows a base class to be expanded upon. So I'm again left with having to call specific classes. Abstract classes won't work for a similar reason.

Comment: @TankorSmash I want to call multiple classes with one class. So that I don't have a giant if statement that says if I'm supposed to be adding class1, class1.add. If I'm supposed to be adding class2, class2.add. I'll just have set masterclass to class2, and now use it.

Comment: @Ken The case you're describing is a virtual method. Inheritance. Use the `sealed` keyword if further inheritance really *is* a problem (unlikely). Please add a section to your question describing in detail, persuasively, why "allowing a base class to be expanded upon" is a problem.

Comment: It sounds like you want to have multiple classes that implement `ISubtract` (or something like that) and choose between different ones. That's pretty normal. But I'm not sure what the "master" is. Does there need to be a master?

Comment: @Ken Please show some code illustrating what you think this would look like.

Comment: I updated my initial question. Hopefully that does it.

Comment: @Ken Yes, I was starting to suspect you didn't understand the difference between a class and an instance of a class. You need to learn basic C# concepts before you can go any further. When you do, come back and read Icepickle's excellent and correct answer below.

Answer (score 3):

You could do it in several ways, either you use interfaces, and implement it like for example:

```
public interface ICalculate {
    void Add();
    void Subtract();
}
```

and implement your classes in such a way that they inherit from the interface, like so:

```
public class SpecificClass : ICalculate {
    public void Add() {
        // ...
    }

    public void Subtract() {
        // ...
    }
}

public class OtherSpecificClass : ICalculate {
    public void Add() {
        // ...
    }

    public void Subtract() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

or you can use an abstract base class like:

```
public abstract class AbstractCalculate {
    public abstract void Add();
    public abstract void Subtract();
}
```

and implement specific classes like:

```
public class SpecificCalculate : AbstractCalculate {
    public override void Add() {
        // ...
    }

    public override void Subtract() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

in the first example you can create your specific classes like:

```
ICalculate calc1 = new SpecificCalculate();
```

and call

```
calc1.Add();
```

in the second one one, you can use

```
AbstractCalculate calc11 = new SpecificCalculate();
```

and call

```
calc1.Add();
```

both have a similar way of working, both have their advantages

more info you can find for example on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149.aspx)

Per suggestion of [Ed Plunkett](https://stackoverflow.com/users/424129/ed-plunkett), you could have then for example following implementations (lets say for the `ICalculate` version)

```
IList<ICalculate> calculations = new List<ICalculate>();

// <-- add specific instances to the list
calculations.Add( new SpecificClass() );
calculations.Add( new OtherSpecificClass() );

// iterate the list
foreach (var calculation in calculations) {
    calculation.Add(); 
}
```

or to be more specific to your updated question

```
public interface IAnimal {
    int GetLegs();
}

public class Bird : IAnimal {
    public int GetLegs() {
        return 2;
    }
}

public class Cat : IAnimal {
    public int GetLegs() {
        return 4;
    }
}
```

and the program would use it like

```
class Program {
    static int GetLegs(IAnimal animal) {
        return animal.GetLegs();
    }

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        Cat cat = new Cat();
        Bird bird = new Bird();

        Console.WriteLine( GetLegs( bird ) ); // 2
        Console.WriteLine( GetLegs( cat ) ); // 4
    }
}
```

Or like

```
IList<IAnimal> animals = new List<IAnimal>();
animals.Add( new Cat() );
animals.Add( new Bird() );

int totalLegs = 0;
foreach (var animal in animals) {
    totalLegs += animal.GetLegs(); // or totalLegs += GetLegs( animal );
}
Console.WriteLine( totalLegs ); // 6
```

Comment: Thanks...but I don't want to call calc1. I want to call calc...and calc will know if it's calc1 or calc2. It's almost like a c++ template...almost...

Comment: @Ken your comments are a bit unclear, you mean to register certain `ICalculate` classes to a class, and then iterate add for all those classes when your main class calls `add`?

Comment: @Icepickle He doesn't understand that the actual object referenced by `calc1` could be a different subclass. With the talk about `calc` vs `calc1`, he may not even understand that `calc1` is just an arbitrary identifier. I'd suggest rewriting your example so it's looping over a `List<AbstractCalculate>` which is explicitly populated with various subclasses -- that might get the idea across. What he thinks he wants might be compile-time duck-typing as in C++ templates, which makes no sense at all for his case. In C++ you'd use a virtual function, of course.

Comment: @Ken, you need to research interfaces.  This is exactly how I'd have answered.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Did my best to add a hopefully clear explanation :)

Comment: @Icepickle Thanks!